# reduceRight in Protractor

Tags: javascript, arrays, testing, protractor

There are two ways to reduce regular javascript arrays:

- [`reduce()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.reduce) (from-left-to-right)
- [`reduceRight()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.reduceRight) (from-right-to-left)

In Protractor, there is [`reduce()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.reduce) which would work from the left element to the very right:

> Apply a reduce function against an accumulator and every element found using the locator (from left-to-right).

Is there `reduceRight()` method in Protractor and, if not, would it be possible to implement it based on `reduce()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there reduceRight() method in Protractor?

No, protractor doesn't support this method.

> Would it be possible to implement it based on reduce()?

Sure, just replace the `arr.reduce` by `arr.reduceRight` in the reduce method:

```
protractor.ElementArrayFinder.prototype.reduceRight = function (reduceFn, initialValue) {
  var valuePromise = protractor.promise.fulfilled(initialValue);
  return this.asElementFinders_().then(function(arr) {
    return arr.reduceRight(function(valuePromise, elementFinder, index) {
      return valuePromise.then(function(value) {
        return reduceFn(value, elementFinder, index, arr);
      });
    }, valuePromise);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's not too expensive in your use-case, you could use `reverse()` first and then a regular `reduce()`.